# jQuery to track leadchat.io box

Tags: jquery, chatbot

i am trying to write a jQuery script do stuff when the leadchat.io box is clicked.

The script i'm using is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $( "#minimize" ).click(function() {
        console.log("hello");
    });
});
```

The site is: http://2.internetremovals.com.au/

I have swapped #minimize with #logo, and it's working perfectly. Something about the chat box loading seperately by a third party is preventing it from registering a click event.

Any suggestions/advice/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though `#minimize` isn't loaded into the DOM on page load. As such, `.ready()` won't apply the click handler, as the element won't exist for it to apply the handler to!

To get around this, the easiest way is to apply a click handler to an element that will **definitely** exist, such as `body`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('body').on('click', '#minimize', function() {
    console.log("hello");
  });
});
```

This way the handler gets added to `body`, which always exists, so it will always have the handler applied. Then it will fire off the function based on the click of the specified selector (in this case, `#minimize`).

Hope this helps! :)